# Tasks - No access to the RecordTypeId field. The field has been removed from the entity or access to this field has been removed

Tags: lightning, tasks, event

here is my issue

1. I create a task from an activity bloc of an account
2. I create an event from event bloc of an account
3. I go back to my task to mark it as done or modify it, i got this message error : `No access to the RecordTypeId field. The field has been removed from the entity or access to this field has been removed`

I specify that :

- this happens randomly
- I have a record type on event but no record type on activities

thank you for your help

Comment: recordtypes are defined on events and tasks; "activities" always refers to both concrete sobjects: Task and Event. Do you have any automation that runs on Task that is using dynamic Apex/DML to update the `Task.RecordTypeId`?

Comment: No automation runs on Task

Comment: Did you ever find out how to resolve this? I have the same thing happening to my users sporadically. I'm totally stumped.